# Identifying ragams in M. L. Vasanthakumari's rendition of *Sancharadadhara*, Jayadeva's *Gita Govindam*

Tags: raga, indian-classical

I've been listening to an album of the Great Masters series released by Nadham Music Media, titled "Revathi - Vol. 2" (2006), a compilation of renditions by [Dr. M. L. Vasanthakumari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._L._Vasanthakumari). The third track in the album is *Sancharadadhara*, an [*ashtapadi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashtapadi) of [Jayadeva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayadeva)'s [*Gita Govindam*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gita_Govinda). I believe this is the fifth *ashtapadi*, but I could be mistaken.

I couldn't find a link to the exact track online, but [this version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qhWxBh2hWs) is close enough for the purposes of my question. MLV sings 4 couplets, each in a different ragam, and I'm curious to identify the ragams.

- The first ragam is definitely [*Mohanam*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohanam), which is quite appropriate since the first line ends with "*mukharita* ***mohana*** *vamsham*".
- The next couple of ragams are not clear to me. In fact, I don't think I've heard the second ragam anywhere before.
- The last ragam is definitely [*Sindubhairavi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sindhu_Bhairavi_(raga)), a popular ragam that often occurs at the end of a *ragamalika* (a composition which uses multiple ragams, literally meaning "a garland of ragams") or sung at the end of a concert.

Can anyone help me identify the middle two ragams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second ragam is called *Gāvati*, a Hindustani ragam that has been borrowed into Carnatic music. It has the following *ārohanam* and *avarohanam*:

**Ārohanam:** S M1 P N2 S
**Avarohanam:** S D2 M1 P G3 M1 R2 S

[G. N. Balasubramaniam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._N._Balasubramaniam) has actually composed a *varnam* (*Kamala vāsini*, Ādi talam) in this ragam. It was GNB who introduced it into Carnatic music, after having learnt it from [Bade Ghulam Ali Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bade_Ghulam_Ali_Khan) in exchange for teaching the Ustad the ragam *Āndolikā*. It makes further sense that MLV sings *Gāvati* since she was a close disciple of GNB.

For the third ragam, first note that MLV switches to *madhyama shruti*. The shift occurs at the [2:34](https://youtu.be/4qhWxBh2hWs?t=153) mark when she ends "*vilasam*" at the note Ma. Then, taking this as Sa, she sings the next couplet, and changes back to the usual *shruti* when she ends "*parihasam*" at the [4:17](https://youtu.be/4qhWxBh2hWs?t=254) mark. The ragam is *Yamuna Kalyāni*, which is often sung in *madhyama shruti*. Compare it with the opening couplet of [*Bhaja Govindam*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8slUawzmPc)  rendered by [M. S. Subbulakshmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._S._Subbulakshmi) or the popular [*Krishna Nee Begane Baro*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ge-Mo_Eu-1U) rendered by MLV to see the similarities.